# Calculate config entity dependencies

Tags: authentication-authorization

I am the maintainer of the Authorization project. It provides a config entity type, the authorization profile. The profile requires two plugin types: provider and consumer. Other modules supply the provider and consumer.

I want to set the authorization profile dependencies to the modules providing the plugins.

Yaml:

```
dependencies:
  module:
    - authorization_drupal_roles
    - ldap_authorization
```

Php:

```php
$config_factory = \Drupal::service('config.factory');
$config = $config_factory->getEditable('authorization.authorization_profile.ldap_group_to_role');

$config->setDependencies([
  'module' => [
    'authorization_drupal_roles',
    'ldap_authorization',
  ],
]);

$config->save();
```

How do I know which module a plugin is from? Does this need to be added as a property in the plugin annotation?

How can I determine the provider plugin is from ldap_authorization, and the consumer plugin is from authorization_drupal_roles?

https://www.drupal.org/project/authorization

Comment: Could you please adjust the question to make what you are asking more obvious?

Comment: Yes I also can't really understand what is being asked.